# Authentication Fails when enabling "Force Change Password on Next Login" using OpenDJ/OpenAM

Tags: openam, opends, reset-password

I'm using OpenAM 9.5.4 and Open DJ 2.4.5 and having problems with "forced password change on reset"

Here are the steps I took to set up my environment:

1) Added a Password Service to the default realm:

> - iplanet-am-password-reset-userValidate=uid
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-searchFilter=objectclass=person
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-baseDN=dc=opensso,dc-java,dc=net
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-lockout-duration=0
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-max-num-of-questions=5
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-question=favourite-restaurant
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-bindPasswd=********
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-failure-duration=300
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-notification=com.sun.identity.password.plugins.EmailPassword
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-lockout-attribute-name=inetuserstatus
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-lockout-attribute-value=inactive
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-lockout-warn-user=4
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-bindDN=cn=openssouser,ou=opensso adminusers,dc=opensso,dc=java,dc=net
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-lockout-email-address=
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-user-personal-question=true
>     RequiredValueValidator=com.sun.identity.sm.RequiredValueValidator
> - **iplanet-am-password-reset-force-reset=true**
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-failure-count=5
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-failure-lockout-mode=true
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-option=com.sun.identity.password.plugins.RandomPasswordGenerator
> - iplanet-am-password-reset-enabled=true

2) Created a password policy in OpenDJ:

> > > > Configure the properties of the Password Policy

```
     Property                                   Value(s)
     -------------------------------------------------------
1)   account-status-notification-handler        -
2)   allow-expired-password-changes             false
3)   allow-user-password-changes                true
4)   default-password-storage-scheme            Salted SHA-1
5)   deprecated-password-storage-scheme         -
6)   expire-passwords-without-warning           false
7)   force-change-on-add                        false
8)   force-change-on-reset                      true
9)   grace-login-count                          0
10)  idle-lockout-interval                      0 s
11)  last-login-time-attribute                  -
12)  last-login-time-format                     -
13)  lockout-duration                           0 s
14)  lockout-failure-count                      0
15)  lockout-failure-expiration-interval        0 s
16)  max-password-age                           2 d
17)  max-password-reset-age                     0 s
18)  min-password-age                           0 s
19)  password-attribute                         userpassword
20)  password-change-requires-current-password  false
21)  password-expiration-warning-interval       1 d
22)  password-generator                         -
23)  password-history-count                     0
24)  password-history-duration                  0 s
25)  password-validator                         -
26)  previous-last-login-time-format            -
27)  require-change-by-time                     -
28)  require-secure-authentication              false
29)  require-secure-password-changes            false

?)   help
f)   finish - apply any changes to the Password Policy
c)   cancel
q)   quit
```

3) Created a Virtual Attribute to assign the password policy to a group of users:

> > > > Configure the properties of the User Defined Virtual Attribute

```
    Property           Value(s)
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
1)  attribute-type     ds-pwp-password-policy-dn
2)  base-dn            The location of the entry in the server is not taken
                       into account when determining whether an entry is
                       eligible to use this virtual attribute.
3)  conflict-behavior  real-overrides-virtual
4)  enabled            true
5)  filter             (objectClass=*)
6)  group-dn           "cn=Users,ou=groups,dc=opensso,dc=java,dc=net"
7)  value              "cn=OpenSSO Users Policy,cn=Password
                       Policies,cn=config"

?)  help
f)  finish - apply any changes to the User Defined Virtual Attribute
c)  cancel
q)  quit
```

4) Created a user

When I go through the Reset Password screens answer the secret question, I get the email to reset the password.  But using the new password (or old) gives and "Authentication Error"

I looked at the user in the OpenDJ Control Panel, the "pwdReset" attribute changed from "false" to "true" as expected.  But if I change it back to "false" I authenticate property, but I'm not forced to change the password.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your settings assume that OpenAM 9.5.4 full supports OpenDJ password policy features.
However this is not the case. I suggest you check the archive of the OpenAM  mailing list, as this has been discussed several times.

Regards,

Ludo

Comment: I have seen the same behavior with OpenAM 10.0.0.  I found mailing list posts that said the feature was only available in the nightly build as of 9.5.4 - does anyone know if this feature has been merged into 10 or is it still not live yet?